# WPF DataGrid: IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ui-virtualization

I have a DataGrid that has a CollectionViewSource bound to it's ItemSource Property:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" RowBackground="#10808080" AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bookingsViewSource}}"
          RowHeight="27"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}" Header="date"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=customers.name}" Header="customer"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=customers.street}" Header="adress"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander Header="{Binding Path=Name}" IsExpanded="True">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

`bookingsViewSource` is defined as

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="bookingsViewSource"
                      d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Database:bookings}}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="providerID"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

and get's filled in code behind section. Everything was doing fine fast and smooth without grouping. But when I added grouping `<PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="providerID"/>` the DataGrid needs around one minute to load.

In .NET 4.5 there is a new Property called `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` and I already set this to true but loading time was not decreasing.

I can not figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

From the book: MacDonald M. - Pro WPF 4.5 in C#

> A number of factors can break UI virtualization, sometimes when you don’t expect it:
>
> - Putting your list control in a ScrollViewer: The ScrollViewer provides a window onto
>     its child content. The problem is that the child content is given unlimited “virtual”
>     space. In this virtual space, the ListBox renders itself at full size, with all of its child
>     items on display. As a side effect, each item gets its own memory-hogging
>     ListBoxItem object. This problem occurs any time you place a ListBox in a container
>     that doesn’t attempt to constrain its size; for example, the same problem crops up if
>     you pop it into a StackPanel instead of a Grid.
> - Changing the list’s control template and failing to use the ItemsPresenter: The
>     ItemsPresenter uses the ItemsPanelTemplate, which specifies the
>     VirtualizingStackPanel. If you break this relationship or if you change the
>     ItemsPanelTemplate yourself so it doesn’t use a VirtualizingStackPanel, you’ll lose
>     the virtualization feature.
> - Not using data binding: It should be obvious, but if you fill a list programmatically—
>     for example, by dynamically creating the ListBoxItem objects you need—no
>     virtualization will occur. Of course, you can consider using your own optimization
>     strategy, such as creating just those objects that you need and only creating them at
>     the time they’re needed. You’ll see this technique in action with a TreeView that uses
>     just-in-time node creation to fill a directory tree in Chapter 22.
>     If you have a large list, you need to avoid these practices to ensure good performance.

Also, in my case the issue was caused by `MahApps.Metro` styles.

Comment: Also experienced incredible slow down once grouping was enabled and just happened to be using MahApps metro for styling.  In fact, the performance hit was so severe it made the application unusable as soon as you tried to expand a group.  Luckily I stumbled on this post which pointed towards the style of the grid as being a possible cause and indeed it was.  If you wish to keep MahApps style in place, only a single property being set on your datagrid is needed to resolve the performance issue.  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"

Comment: The second one, it slows down even if you have VirtualizingStackPanel as your ItemsPanelTemplate ...